# Gaps in rasters as a result of OBIA. Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I am running an object-oriented classification and I get gaps in the rasters that I want to use.

For example, I want to use elevation data from 'USGS/SRTMGL1_003'. If you run the code, you will see a gap in the elevation layer. I believe something happens when I use the command .reduceConnectedComponents, because the areas that come out as gaps are present in the original images, in the raster with clusters obtained as a result of the SNIC algorithm, and in SRTM. The same thing happens when I set the object size and reproject the rasters. The gaps are different in size, but still present. Since I haven't reprojected it in this code, they will change as you zoom in/out, but they persist even when I set a scale and export the files.

This happens to all the metrics that I want to use (after applying the .reduceConnectedComponents command), not only elevation. My images have a spatial resolution of 2.5 m.

The code is in this [link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/478f16e6167dadc27bec1d3f14aa0320) or below:

```
var clip = ee.FeatureCollection('users/rizayeva/DS1011-1040_geometry');
var image2 = ee.Image('users/rizayeva/corona_2_5m/DS1011-1040DA_2_5m_JPEG_1band_EPSG32638').rename('ds10111040da');
var image3 = ee.Image('users/rizayeva/corona_2_5m/DS1011-1040DF_2_5m_JPEG_1band_EPSG32638').rename('ds10111040df');
var img = ee.Image.cat([image2, image3]).divide(255);
Map.addLayer(img, {bands: ["ds10111040df", "ds10111040df", "ds10111040da"], gamma: 0.8}, 'DS1011-1040');
Map.centerObject(ee.Geometry.Point(44.5567, 41.7856), 10);

var elevation = ee.Image('USGS/SRTMGL1_003').select('elevation').clip(clip);
// var imageVisParams = {bands: ['elevation'], min: 1, max: 3445,  gamma: [1.85], opacity: 1};
Map.addLayer(elevation, {min: 1, max: 3445,  gamma: [1.85], opacity: 1}, 'Elevation', false);

//Segmentation
var seeds = ee.Algorithms.Image.Segmentation.seedGrid(40);
// Run SNIC on the regular square grid.
var snic = ee.Algorithms.Image.Segmentation.SNIC({
  image: img, 
  size: 32,
  compactness: 0.1,
  connectivity: 4,
  neighborhoodSize:256,
  seeds: seeds
}).select(['ds10111040da_mean', 'ds10111040df_mean', 'clusters'], ['ds10111040da', 'ds10111040df', 'clusters']);

var clusters = snic.select('clusters')//.reproject({crs: 'EPSG:4326', scale: 18});
Map.addLayer(clusters.randomVisualizer(), {}, 'clusters', false);
Map.addLayer(snic, {bands: ['ds10111040da', 'ds10111040df'], min:0, max:1, gamma: 0.8}, 'means', false);
var elevation_10111040 = elevation.addBands(clusters).reduceConnectedComponents(ee.Reducer.mean(), 'clusters', 256);
Map.addLayer(elevation_10111040, {min: 1, max: 3445,  gamma: [1.85], opacity: 1}, 'elevation_10111040');

// Export.image.toDrive({
//   image: elevation_10111040,
//   description: "elevation_10111040",
//   folder: "elevation_10111040",
//   scale: 2.5,
//   region: clip,
//   maxPixels:1e13,
// });
```

Comment: Your link is not working, asset doesn't seem to exist or is not set to public

Comment: Thank you @Jobbo90 I think I fixed it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to increase the `maxSize` in `reduceConnectedComponents()`. The docs says:

> maxSize (Integer, default: 256):
>
> Size of the neighborhood to consider when aggregating values. Any objects larger than `maxSize` in either the horizontal or vertical
> dimension will be masked, since portions of the object might be
> outside of the neighborhood.

The masked part in your elevation is an object larger than `maxSize`. I increased it to `1024`, and it rendered. Too large value will cause you to run out of memory though. If that happens, you might be forced to export your results - you have more memory available during exports.

Comment: You are right, it worked! Thank you so much for your help!